# How to add two properties files to JSF

Tags: java, jsf, properties

I have two properties files, but something is wrong, inputStream is always null?

```
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>resources/Bundle</base-name>
        <var>bundle</var>
    </resource-bundle>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>fi</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>fi</supported-locale>

    </locale-config>

    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>resources/avainsanat</base-name>
        <var>avainsanat</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>

 public static List getAvainsanat() throws IOException {
    InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("avainsanat.properties");

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("InputStream is: " + input);

    for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        String value = properties.getProperty(key);
        values.add(value);

    }
    return values;
}
```

Is it even possible to have two or more properties files in faces-config? If not, how can I read from my bundle only those properties which key has a prefix key_?

Thanks
Sami

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to include the `resources` package in the path. The context class loader searches always relative to the classpath root.

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/avainsanat.properties");
```

The more correct way is in this particular case however using [`ResourceBundle#getBundle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29), which is also exactly what JSF is using under the covers for `<resource-bundle>`:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.avainsanat", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale());
// ...
```

*(note that you should actually have used a `<base-name>resources.avainsanat</base-name>`)*

Alternatively, if the bean is request scoped, you could also just inject `#{avainsanat}` as managed property:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{avainsanat}")
private ResourceBundle bundle;
```

Or to programmatically evaluate it:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ResourceBundle bundle = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{avainsanat}", ResourceBundle.class);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks! ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.avainsanat", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale()); Do this give me just values or key value pairs?

Comment: Everything. Just use `keySet()` method to get all keys. See also the javadoc.

Comment: I am ashamed..When you have a keySet, how to loop it to get values? I need just values, not keys at all.

Comment: `for (String key : bundle.keySet()) String value = bundle.getString(key);`

Comment: Thanks, so simple. I was trying it too complicated.